# With Python, GAE and Tipfy, unable to pass a db.key as parameter for image retrieval

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy

Ok, so I'm playing around with tipfy, making a simple photo-gallery. I have a working solution using webbapp, this is my template, browse.htm, which stays the same in both examples:

```
{% for pic in photo_list %}
<tr>
  <td><img src='getPic?img_id={{ pic.key }} '></img></td>
  <td>{{ pic.description }}</td>
  <td>{{ pic.date }}</td>
</tr>
```

and this is my databsemodel, which also satys the same

```
# This is the datamodell for the photos
class dbPhotos(db.Model):
  pic = db.BlobProperty() # The photo itself
  description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True) # an optional description to each photo from the uploader
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)   # date and time of upload
```

So, using webapp, my script is:

```
# the handler for the gallery page
class BrowseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    que = db.Query(dbPhotos)
    photos = que.fetch(limit=100)
    outstr = template.render('browse.htm', {'photo_list': photos})
    handler.response.out.write(outstr)

# serve pics to template
class getPicHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    userphoto = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
    self.response.out.write(userphoto.pic)
```

So, this works perfectly. Now, trying to use tipfy, i do:

```
# the handler for the browse-page
class browseHandler(RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    que = db.Query(dbPhotos)
    photos = que.fetch(limit=100)
    return render_response('browse.ji', photo_list=photos)

# serve pic to view
class getPicHandler(RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    id = self.request.args.get("img_id")
    userphoto = db.get(id)
    return Response(userphoto.pic, mimetype='image/png')
```

Now, this last example does not work perfectly. **It does fetch all the comments and dates and displays them correctly**, but *no pictures*.

I'm so stuck on this, any input is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to get it to work, the solution was to change the template from

```
{% for pic in photo_list %}
  <tr>
  <td><img src='getPic?img_id={{ pic.key }} '></img></td>
```

To

```
{% for pic in photo_list %}
  <tr>
  <td><img src='getPic?img_id={{ pic.key() }} '></img></td>
```

Anoyone care to comment on why this is the solution is very welcome

Comment: Presumably tipfy is not using the same templating language as webapp.

Comment: sure, tipfy uses jinja and webapp uses django - but i still dont get why it represents all the other fields e.g. `{{ pic.date }}` correctly, but not `{{ pic.key }}`